# SSH computer_name.local issues

Tags: macos, ssh, localhost, file-sharing

This question may be rather elementary, but I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I do my research on a MacBook Pro, and I have access to my university's Mac desktops which run my codes faster; so I wanted to share my files with the uni's Mac. Without thinking too much, I ran

```
ssh my_laptops_name.local
```

on the uni's Mac, and this allowed me to access all my files on the uni's Mac, which was great! Any file I create/delete on either my laptop or the uni's Mac are instantly synced.

The issue is that anyone who uses this uni's specific Mac can now mess around with my files. How do I end this synchronous file sharing between my laptop and the desktop? (I tried turning off file sharing on my laptop and it did not work). Additionally, what is a better method for me to use to share files and stop sharing files when I so please? I realize I should have thought this through more beforehand--feel free to shame me.

Comment: First: stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or networking; [superuser](https://superuser.com) or the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be better places to ask about this. Second: ssh does not do file synchronization, at least by itself. You must've done something else (or you might be confused about where things are), so you'll need to provide more information about exactly what you did and what you're seeing.

Comment: Does your university have a help desk? You might want to direct the question to them, as they will be familiar with the configuration of their workstations, what synchronization software, if any, might be in place, etc. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the right forum for this question...

Comment: @GordonDavisson I understand, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will make sure to direct the question to either of those forums. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob You're right, I didn't even think of reaching out to my Uni's IT department. Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it!